# Data annotations localization for nested class C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to localize data annotations in my ASP.NET Core web API 2 project, my codes works perfectly for normal classes but its not working with nested class C#. Is there anything wrong with my codes? Is it even supported in .NET Core ?

Normal class works :

```
namespace ShagerdanehAPI.Models.API
{
    public class APIInputs
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is not valid.")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }
}
```

but Nested class are not working:

```
namespace ShagerdanehAPI.Models.API
{
    public class APIInputs
    {
        public  class InputLogin
        {

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]
            [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is not valid.")]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string UserName { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Project structure :

[image]

Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                         options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(ApplicationRole), builder.Services);
        builder.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>();
        builder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        builder.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        //add Localization
        services.AddSingleton<localizationService>();
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        //add roles
        services.AddMvcCore()
        .AddAuthorization()
        .AddJsonFormatters()
        .AddDataAnnotations()
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
            options =>
            {
                List<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                    {
                                    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                                    new CultureInfo("fa-IR")
                    };
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "fa-IR", uiCulture: "fa-IR");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

                options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(context =>
                {

                    string userLangs = context.Request.Headers["Accept-Language"].ToString();
                    string firstLang = userLangs.Split(',').FirstOrDefault();
                    string defaultLang = string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstLang) ? "fa-IR" : firstLang;
                    return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(defaultLang, defaultLang));
                }));

            });
        services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
        });
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ApiName = "api1";

            });
        services.Configure<ShagerdanehConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("ShagerdanehConfig"));
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                building => building.WithOrigins(
                    "http://localhost:3000",
                    "http://192.168.30.2:3000",
                       AllowAnyMethod()
                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                  .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)));
        });
    }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Sent Json:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for updating with more info. When the request object is created ASP.NET has to create an instance of nested class to do validation against it, even your updated code doesn't have an instance of the nested class. All you've done is defined the blue print of nested class and have not created an instance of it. Also if you change to nested, your request structure also should be nested.

`public UserInfo UserData { get; set; } //Is the key to your problem, instance of nested class.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nested class' instance should be defined in the Nesting Outer class. Validation works fine once you do that.

My Model:

```
public class UserDetailNested
{
    // Property Instance in Outer class
    public UserInfo UserData { get; set; }

    public class UserInfo
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is not valid.")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller Method:

```
// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]UserDetailNested userDetail)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    else
        return Ok();
}
```

Screenshot of response:
[image: Insomnia Rest Client Screenshot]

Comment: @Oli Can you share the Json request that you're passing to the endpoint? Add that too to the question, so its easy for people who try to help you. I've updated the property name in my answer (changed name while posting code, that caused issue), hope fixed code helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the nesting and where it expects the translations to be located. The working first example is looking for the translations in APIInputs in the resources directory. Whereas the second example is looking for it in APIInputs > InputLogin which isnt there.

One approach would be

```
namespace ShagerdanehAPI.Models.API
{
    public class LoginDetails
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is not valid.")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then create:

```
namespace ShagerdanehAPI.Models.API
{
    public class APIInputs
    {
         public LoginDetails UserLoginDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Your resource file should be renamed LoginDetails.fa-IR.resx

As you will see the translation properties are in LoginDetails and not in APIInputs so thats where it will look. You could add additional properties to the APIInputs class add if the model validation is on them you could then add a resource class as you have done APIInputs.fa-IR.resx and it will get that property translation from there and the other translations would be retrieved from LoginDetails.fa-IR.resx.